# How to set domain name (or host name) on Wildfly-8.2.1.Final

Tags: java, wildfly-8, ear

I have developed an EAR application having structure like,

abc.ear

- def.war
- def1.war
- ghi.jar

I want to launch it as a website. How to configure the domain name in Wildfly-8.2.1. ?

IP to Domain Name mapping already done and I can access the application using,

```
http://<some-domain-name>:8080/HelloWorld/
```

But I want to access the site by entering the domain name only. 
i.e.

`http://<some-domain-name>`

Really appreciate for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should call this the hostname rather than the domain name. While you're technically correct, domain names have another significance in application servers where you can group servers in domains that help with administration and exploitation tasks

Comment: @Aaron. I am restructuring the query. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This describes how to change the context root](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7) (the path after the domain name).

Just set `<context-root>/</context-root>` in your jboss-web.xml.

You also want to change the port to 80, which is the default for http. For this, you have to change the socket-binding of your public interface. You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Interfaces+and+ports) for more information.

In your <server>.xml you should find a 
`<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">` tag. Change the contained `<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>` to define port 80 instead of 8080.

Comment: I already have <some-domain-name> mapped with some IP. What should be the next step. Please elaborate.

Comment: I think I gave you all the elements needed to make it work in a standard environment. Do you have any specific error or anything that could hint to a specific point of failure?